# NPE injecting Singleton bean into a Singleton bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi

I'm having a weird problem where I get a NullPointerException when injecting a singleton bean (class B) into another singleton bean (class A) where both beans are using EJB 3.1 annotations. The NPE occurs because the map is null when accessing from class A even though class B was injected.
eg:

```java
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class A {
    @Inject
    B b;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialise() {
        b.map.put("test", 1);
        System.out.println("A initialised");
    }
}
```

```java
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import java.util.HashMap;

@Singleton
public class B {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialise() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println("B initialised");
    }
}
```

However, if I use the CDI singleton annotation for class B, the code executes as expected:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.HashMap;

@Singleton
public class B {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialise() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println("B initialised");
    }
}
```

Is there a reason why the EJB annotation is not working in this situation?

Comment: Try using eager initialization with class `B` as well - e.g. use `@Startup`. This way I suspect that B might not yet be initialized (you only get some sort of proxy object) and you try to access it way too soon.

Comment: Just tried @Startup again to be sure but still throwing an NPE. Even tried @DependsOn("B") in A but that also hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between @EJB and @Inject.
Unfortunately CDI and EJB annotations are similar but might not work the same way!

In your case the Bean B is correct injected with CDI if it is a CDI Bean (annotated with CDI Singleton annotation)

I would assume the EJB injection will work if you use @EJB instead of @Inject - if Bean B is annotated with javax.ejb.Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

An important fact that many fail to realise is that an EJB client only sees a "view" of the *public methods of an EJB* where ever it is injected.

You are attempting to access one of it's instance variables directly:

```
    b.map.put("test", 1);
```

If you add a delegate method to EJB `B`:

```
public Integer put(String key, Integer value) {
    return map.put(key, value);
}
```

and invoke it:

```
@PostConstruct
public void initialise() {
    b.put("test", 1);
    System.out.println("A initialised");
}
```

then you will get

> 20:18:16,823 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) B initialised
>   20:18:16,824 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) A initialised

as expected.

See §3 of the EJB specification for more information. Here you will find the statement:

> The container provides security, concurrency, transactions, swapping to secondary storage, and other services for the session object transparently to the client.

If you were to successfully access the instance variable directly then you would bypass all of this.